# Rangy and InsertNode issue

Tags: dom, rangy

I am selecting a word and trying to replace it with a element structure. Earlier I was using `IE=EmulateIE7` and the below code was working. Due to few other issues I removed the Emulate IE7 meta and the insertNode below stopped working.

```
function updateNodeAtRange(text, frag) {
    var range = getFirstRange();
var htmlcontent='<span id="AuniqueId" class="style1">'+frag+'</span><span id="BuniqueId" class="style2">'+text+'</span>';
if (range) {
    rangy.getSelection().deleteFromDocument();
    var el = document.createElement("new_update");
    el.setAttribute( 'id', 'CuniqueId' );
    el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text)); //Not sure if this is right
    el.innerHTML = htmlcontent;
    range.insertNode(el);
    rangy.getSelection().setSingleRange(range);
}
alert( document.getElementById('Filearea').innerHTML );
}
```

The new_update element is not at all required but it works at this stage. Also instead of `innerHTML` can I use `document.createDocumentFragment()` ?. Then how do I insert in that location.

Answer (score 1):

I assume `getFirstRange()` calls `rangy.getSelection().getRangeAt(0)`?

One issue is that your text node is getting wiped out by the following line, but without more to go on (a demo page would be ideal), it's impossible to say what the main problem is. One possibility is that `range` has been altered by the `deleteFromDocument()` call. I would advise getting a new range from the selection before inserting the node:

```
function updateNodeAtRange(text, frag) {
    var sel = rangy.getSelection();
    if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
        var htmlcontent='<span id="AuniqueId" class="style1">'
            +frag+'</span><span id="BuniqueId" class="style2">'
            +text+'</span>';
        sel.deleteFromDocument();
        var el = document.createElement("new_update");
        el.setAttribute( 'id', 'CuniqueId' );
        el.innerHTML = htmlcontent;
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
        range.insertNode(el);
        sel.setSingleRange(range);
    }
    alert( document.getElementById('Filearea').innerHTML );
}
```

Comment: I changed `rangy.getSelection().deleteFromDocument()` to `range.deleteContents();` and it worked fine.